# How to use styles defined in App.xaml in a other library in a wpf application?

Tags: wpf, resources, styles, app.xaml

I've got a main project that is producing my executable. In the App.xaml I am defining some base styles.
Now I want to use this styles in other projects respectively in other libraries (dlls).
I read all the questions about this problems here in stackoverflow, but it doesn't work for me.
Could it be, that I get this problems, because I want to use the styles in the libraries referenced by the main project?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 2):

You should move these styles to a separate [Resource Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which could be used by multiple projects/applications.

Create the resource dictionary and add it to your project and then reference it in your App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="\shared\MyResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new WPF User Control Library, add a `ResourceDictionary` to this project and move your styles from `App.xaml` to this `ResourceDictionary`. Then you add a reference (Project->Add Reference in Visual Studio) to this new project from your WPF application and any other application in which you want to use these styles and merge the `ResourceDictionary` into the `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfControlLibrary1;component/ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application>
```

Obviously you need to change "WpfControlLibrary1" and "ResourceDictionary1" to the actual names of the new project and `ResourceDictionary` respectively.

This way you have moved the common styles to a stand-alone assembly that you could use in many different applications.